# Calling a "Method" inside a FOR loop in a batch file

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file

I am writing a batch file to start and stop different Oracle DB instances I have running on my machine.  If each DB is called TestDB1 through TestDB11, I want to first ask what DB Instance I want to start, Start that instance, and then cycle through all the other instance except that one and stop them.  I'm close, but I feel like I'm missing something in the FOR loop structure.  Here is the code I have:

```
TITLE Service and Server Starter
@ECHO OFF

:startQuestion
CHOICE /M "Would you like to start a specific DB instance"
IF errorlevel 2 GOTO :end
IF errorlevel 1 GOTO :dbStart

:dbStart
set /P instance=Please Enter the Test Instance Name:
IF /I "%instance%"=="" GOTO :dbStart
net start OracleJobScheduler"%instance%"
net start OracleService"%instance%"
net start OracleVssWriter"%instance%" 
CALL :dbEndTest1 "%instance%"
GOTO :EOF

:dbEndTest1
set pass=%~1
set var=%pass:~-1%
FOR /L %%n in (1,1,11) DO (
    CALL :dbEndTest2 %%n "%var%")

:dbEndTest2
set var=%~1
set instance=%~2
IF NOT "%var%"=="%instance%" (
        @ECHO "Stopping Test%var%"
        sc stop OracleJobSchedulerTest"%var%"
        sc stop OracleServiceTest"%var%"
        sc stop OracleVssWriterTest"%var%"
    )
)
exit /B

:entryError
set /P Error=Please enter a y or n for your server start.
IF /I "%Error%"=="" GOTO :startQuestion

:end
```

The output I am getting right now is that say I'm wanting to start TestDB2, I type in TestDB1 to answer the question, those 3 services will get started.

It will then move to the :dbEndTest1, it will correctly pull off the last character in the string, in this case "2", enter the FOR loop, and begin stopping the first instance if it is running, which would be TestDB1.  Then it jumps to the :entryError point and stops, expecting a response.

What have I missed??

Comment: Put `goto :EOF` or `exit /B` after every sub-routine! otherwise the command processor does not know when to return...

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl!  I added the end /B after dbTest2 as you can see above.  This created a new and interesting error.  After it cycled through all 11 db services, it started back over at 1 again.  Do I need a end /B after dbEndTest1 as well?

Comment: So I have tested using end /B and GOTO :EOF after dbEndTest1 and it still starts back over at 1

Comment: You need to end also the main section. Always keep in mind that batch scripts are executed from top to bottom, and to change this, you have to take care yourself; the command processor does not know any concept of true sub-routines or functions... By the way, you do not need the interim variable `validAnswer` when you just place `goto :end` after the `if /I "%startNew%"` queries... Also consider the [`choice` command](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) for such `y`/`n` selections...

Answer (score 0):

I posted my final working code in the initial question above.  Thanks to aschipfl for the help!

Comment: user1971240, you should rollback your question otherwise nobody can see any relevance to the title or the rest of the page. Post your final working code as this answer and if nobody provides a better solution, you could mark your own answer as accepted.